# Filtering columns with characters

Tags: r

I want to filter a column in a dataframe which is weather condition line rainy, clear... and contains characters.

```
` min1$Rainy <- filter(min1$Conditions == "Light Rain")`
```

I tried the codes above but I faced to this error:

> Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class `"logical"`

How can I solve it?
Appreciate for your time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `min1$Rainy` is a column while `filter` produces a dataframe, so how do you want to store a dataframe into a column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `filter` is part of the `tidyverse` family, it follows the standard `tidyverse` interface. The first argument needs to be a `tbl_df` (data frame).

Comment: How can I do that?
Can you explain more please?

Comment: `min1 <- filter(min1, Conditions == "Light Rain") `.  If you just want the Rainy column, `Rainy <- filter(min1, Conditions == "Light Rain")  %>% pull(Rainy)`

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can write a code to filter more than one Condition? I don't know the correct form of command.
For instance, something like this: 
Rain <- filter(dataframe, Conditions == "Light Rain" & "Light Rain Showers")

Comment: `Rain <- filter(dataframe, Conditions == "Light Rain" | Conditions == "Light Rain Showers")`